# Is there any alternative to react-native-picker/picker for expo project?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I just don't like the wheel option that iOS displays for react-native-picker/picker and I couldn't find an alternative so far so hoping someone will point me in the right direction.

I've used Picker from react-native-picker/picker but is there a way to get rid of the wheel option that iOS displays for an expo project? I would rather just a dropdown menu.